# How to make a Widget slide view with Qt4?

Tags: animation, qt4, pyqt4, slideshow

I currently display several widgets (quite large ones, almost screen-wide) on a [QStackedLayout](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstackedlayout.html), let's call these widgets "pages". Switching from a page to another is done with buttons below (previous, index, next).

I would like pages to slide while switching, as if they were placed on a larger-than-screen row, moving left or right depending on what the user wants.

For this I thought the [QScrollArea](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qscrollarea.html) would be OK, but I can add only one widget to it and I cannot index sub-items to move accordingly nor can I force a per-item-scroll (I don't want the sliding movement to stop between two pages.)

Another option is the QListView or other derivate from [QAbstractItemView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html), but I can't find how to pass a widget as a QListItemModel or other reimplemented [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemmodel.html). [Roles for data are quite limited](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum), and none seem to allow QWidgets.

How can I proceed to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems using a QScrollArea and scroll programmatically using the inherited [`scrollContentsBy()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractslider.html#value-prop) would do the trick. The viewport then would be an elongated widget, sliding left or right so one section could be seen at a time.